# Image Resizing : The operation completed successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-processing

Goodmorning everyone.

I have the following problem: in an MVC application I created a handler for downloading images, scaling and so on. It seems to work fine but somethimes in event viewer I get an error and I would not know where to start to find or even look for a solution.

error: "The operation completed successfully." It occurs by instantiating a "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder"

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: Win32Exception 
    Exception message: The operation completed successfully
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder..ctor(Boolean isBuiltIn)
   at Totalcom.Drawing.ImageHelper.GetResizedImage(Byte[] bytes, Nullable`1 w, Nullable`1 h, Nullable`1 maxWidth, Nullable`1 maxHeight, Boolean keepRatio, Boolean crop, String backgroudColor, String imageFormat, Int32 dpi, Int32 quality)
```

UPDATE: the code

```
/// <summary>
/// return byte of the resized image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bytes">The bytes on original image.</param>
/// <param name="w">desidered width.</param>
/// <param name="h">desired height</param>
/// <param name="maxWidth">The maximum width.</param>
/// <param name="maxHeight">The maximum height.</param>
/// <param name="keepRatio">if set to <c>true</c> mantain ratio.</param>
/// <param name="crop">if set to <c>true</c> crop the resulting image.</param>
/// <param name="backgroudColor">Color of the backgroud.</param>
/// <param name="imageFormat">The image format.</param>
/// <param name="dpi">The dpi.</param>
/// <param name="quality">The quality.</param>
/// <returns></returns>

public static byte[] GetResizedImage(

        byte[] bytes
        , int? w
        , int? h
        , int? maxWidth
        , int? maxHeight
        , bool keepRatio
        , bool crop
        , string backgroudColor
        , string imageFormat
        , int dpi = 96
        , int quality = 90
)
{
    int width = w.HasValue && w > 0 ? w.Value : 0;
    int height = h.HasValue && h > 0 ? h.Value : 0;


    if (bytes.Length == 0)
    {
        return bytes;
    }
    Image img = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }

            /* se ho specificato maxwidth o maxwidth, devo verificare se devo fare il resize o meno */
    if (maxWidth.HasValue || maxHeight.HasValue)
    {
                /*  verifico se devo fare il resize */
        if (
                (maxWidth.HasValue && img.Width < maxWidth)
                        ||
                        (maxHeight.HasValue && img.Height < maxHeight)
                )
        {
            return bytes;
        }
        else
        {
            if (maxWidth.HasValue && (maxWidth < width || width <= 0))
            {
                width = maxWidth.Value;
            }
            if (maxHeight.HasValue && (maxHeight < height || height <= 0))
            {
                height = maxHeight.Value;
            }
        }
    }


    if (img.IsAnimated())
    {
                /* prendo il primo frame */
        img = img.GetFrame(0);
    }


    decimal resizeX = width;
    decimal resizeY = height;


    // Calcolo le dimensioni dell'immagine
            /* Se non ho specificato altezza o largnezza, ma il ratio
             * calcolo il parametro mancante*/
    if (height > 0 & width <= 0 && keepRatio)
    {
        width = height * img.Width / img.Height;
        resizeX = width;
    }
    else if (width > 0 & height <= 0 && keepRatio)
    {
        height = width * img.Height / img.Width;
        resizeY = height;
    }
    else
    {
                /* crop 
                   calcolo quale lato si deve adattare */
        if (crop)
        {
            if ((decimal)img.Width / (decimal)width > (decimal)img.Height / (decimal)height)
            {
                resizeY = height;
                resizeX = resizeY * img.Width / img.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                resizeX = width;
                resizeY = resizeX * img.Height / img.Width;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((width * 100 / img.Width) < (height * 100 / img.Height))
            {
                // Se è più largo
                resizeX = width;
                resizeY = width * img.Height / img.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                // Se è più alto
                resizeY = height;
                resizeX = height * img.Width / img.Height;
            }
        }
    }


    int newW = width;
    int newH = height;

    if (keepRatio)
    {
        newW = (int)resizeX;
        newH = (int)resizeY;

    }


    // Disegno l'immagine
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {

        bmp.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);


        Color c = Color.White;
        if (imageFormat == CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE_PNG)
        {
            c = Color.Transparent;
        }
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(backgroudColor))
            {

                try
                {
                    if (backgroudColor.Substring(0, 1) != "#")
                    {
                        backgroudColor = String.Format("#{0}", backgroudColor);
                    }

                    c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(backgroudColor);

                }
                catch { }

            }
            gr.Clear(c);


            // Disegno l'immagine centrata
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            gr.DrawImage(img, (width - newW) / 2, (height - newH) / 2, newW, newH);

        }

        // Salvo l'immagine nello stream
        try
        {
            byte[] result = null;
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var codec = GetImageCodeInfo(imageFormat);
                bmp.Save(m, GetImageCodeInfo(imageFormat), GetEncoderParameters(imageFormat));
                result = m.GetBuffer();
            }

            BitmapEncoder targetEncoder;
            if (imageFormat == CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE_PNG)
            {
                targetEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder()
                {

                };
            }
            else
            {
                targetEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder
                {
                    QualityLevel = quality
                };
            }

            var frame = ReadBitmapFrame(result);
            var resize = FastResize(frame, width, height);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                targetEncoder.Frames.Add(resize);
                targetEncoder.Save(memoryStream);
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }


            targetEncoder = null;
            frame = null;
            resize = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            return result;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
        {
            //errore generico

            //TODO : loggare l'errore
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}


public static BitmapFrame ReadBitmapFrame(byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapFrame result;

    using (MemoryStream photoStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var photoDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(
                photoStream,
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                BitmapCacheOption.None);

        result = photoDecoder.Frames[0];
    }
    return result;
}


public static BitmapFrame FastResize(BitmapFrame photo, int width, int height)
{
    var target = new TransformedBitmap(
            photo,
            new System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform(
                    width / photo.Width,
                    height / photo.Height,
                    0, 0));
    return BitmapFrame.Create(target);
}
```

Comment: Please post your problematic code.

Comment: i modify the post and add the code

Comment: When and which line of the code you receive the error?

Comment: I think that is this line: targetEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder

Comment: the problem seems that i have no more handles. Probably i do not finalize any object, but i cannot understand what object

Comment: Why you don't use [ImageResizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer.FluentExtensions.Mvc) instead? read this post for more info (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx)[http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx]

Comment: Image resize suck. it need a lot of memory. I have many sites on my server. My solution works, but somethims i have this errors in my event log

Comment: I update the post. This error appears only in my event viewer and not all the days and not anways on same hour. The site apparently work correctly and manage over 10.000 page views pro day. But i found about 50 entries in event viewer with this error pro day